# Sorting in nodejs not stable, implications for memory usage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting

I currently have a memory issue when sorting some very big arrays in nodejs. I'm using the build in sort method. We have an array that contains many duplicates e.g. 
[1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3](Clarification: however the thing we are actually sorting is an array of JSONObjects, where the keys we are sorting by are mostly duplicates).
I saw that nodejs sort is in situ but not stable and was wondering whether the not stable part also has implications for the memory in nodejs(I know it shouldn't but well).

Since I didn't find BlockSort implemented to test it, I was wondering if anyone would happen to know. Also more generally if anyone knows a more memory efficient sorting library that I could test I'd be grateful.
An example of what I'm hoping is optimizable

```
function com<T>(a: T, b: T): number {
  if (a > b) {
    return 1;
  }

  if (a < b) {
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}
data.sort((a, b) => com(a.SomeString, b.SomeString))
```

Comment: To remove duplicates try converting to a Set. It is much more perfomant than an array for large datasets.

Comment: I clarified the questions, or do u think it would still be more efficient now?

Comment: Node is based on Chrome, so the sort should be stable.  But I doubt this has anything to do with memory usage.  Could you show some code, is it maybe something your doing in your compare callback?

Comment: I added what it looks like

Comment: @Keith Node is based on V8 not chrome. Sort has only being stable since V8 v7.0, and that version of V8 was implemented first in Node 11. So sort() is not stable in Node 10 or below.

Comment: No, stability of a sort has no implications on memory usage. Not sure why you think the two would relate?